# Wait for script to load before executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I would like to get the code below to wait for another script to be loaded before executing. How can I get this to wait for sp.js to load before executing?

```
$.getScript("/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/jquery.LISP.Quicklaunch.js", function(){});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#s4-leftpanel').quicklaunchHide({
    collapseImage: '/_layouts/images/mewa_leftPage.gif',
    expandImage: '/_layouts/images/mewa_rightPage.gif',
    prependLocation: '.s4-tn',
    mainDiv: '.s4-ca',                            
    leftMargin: 0,    
    hideOnDefault: true,   
    allowCookie: true,
    cookieName: 'quicklaunchStatus'            
});

function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('#s4-mainarea').css('min-height', windowHeight-203);
};
setHeight();

$(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
});

jQuery('#s4-workspace').css('cssText', 'height: 262px !important');
});
```

Comment: There's an example right in the jQuery documentation -- "bind some color animations to occur once the new functionality is loaded": https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: What `sp.js`? You just need to use a callback. If you want to execute your code after that `.getScript()`, put it inside the second parameter, which is a function: `$.getScript('path/to/script.js', function(){ /* your code here */ });`

Comment: Great answer @kmsdev, that is the correct way to accomplish this. Please make it a full answer to get credit and for this question to be closed.

Comment: I put it as comment because I am not entirely sure about if this is what the OP is trying to do exactly. It is what it looks, but I am not sure.

Comment: OP asked for a file called `sp.js` which does not appear in the posted code. Also his answer does not match with his question altogether... The question is not clear. The doubt has gone. @fond42518

Comment: I didn't think the contents of 'sp.js' were relevant for my question. Thank you for all submissions.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you. Welcome to SO by the way. In your question you wrote `How can I get this to wait for sp.js`. If something is not relevant please try to avoid it. Also, the line `$.getScript("/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/jquery.LISP.Quicklaunch.js", function(){});` confused me, I though you were trying to use the callback function of `.getScript()`. You could avoid that line too, it was what confused me more than the js file. It's better isolate the problem as much as possible.

Comment: Did not offend, all is well! :) I will keep this in mind for future posts! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
$.getScript("/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/jquery.LISP.Quicklaunch.js", function(){});


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(delayedExecute, "sp.js");
});

function delayedExecute(){
    jQuery('#s4-leftpanel').quicklaunchHide({
        collapseImage: '/_layouts/images/mewa_leftPage.gif',
        expandImage: '/_layouts/images/mewa_rightPage.gif',
        prependLocation: '.s4-tn',
        mainDiv: '.s4-ca',                            
        leftMargin: 0,    
        hideOnDefault: true,   
        allowCookie: true,
        cookieName: 'quicklaunchStatus'            
    });

    function setHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        listHeight = windowHeight - 180;
        jQuery('#s4-workspace').css('cssText', 'height: ' + listHeight + 'px !important');
    };
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer from comment. Please check the **[jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)**.

You just need to use a callback. If you want to execute your code after that `.getScript()`, put it inside the second parameter, which is currently a callback function:

```
$.getScript('path/to/script.js', function(){ 
    /* your code goes here */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Deferring execution of code is most simply done using a callback. For instance, if you have a function called `defer()` which you only want to execute after a function `dofirst()` has executed, you'd do this:

```
function dofirst(arguments, callback){
    //Do something here first, then call the callback
    callback();
};

function defer(arguments){
    //This is the code which you want to defer until the dofirst code has executed
    return;
}

//Invoke the function here
dofirst(arguments, defer);
```

hope this helps!